# How to Add attribute in Zeep?

Tags: python, odoo, zeep

**How to Add attribute for Item Using Zeep**

The following is an xml code for my SOAP request:

```
<Item actionCode="01">
    <TypeCode>002</TypeCode>
    <Quantity unitCode="EA">1.0</Quantity>
</Item>
```

I would like to add attribute for Item when response with python dictionary using zeep. Can someone help me?